# getResource not work with jar running in docker

Tags: java, docker, jar, getresource

I put `qqwry.dat` in `src/main/resource` in my SpringBoot project. In my class, I tried:

```
IPSeeker.class.getResource("/qqwry.dat"), IPSeeker.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResource("qqwry.dat")
```

Both is OK running on my own computer with tomcat embebed in SpringBoot Tomcat. But when I build them into JAR and run in Docker never worked. Very bothing.

Comment: Have you checked that your jar realy includes this resources? And what is the real name "qqwar.dat" or "qqwry.dat"? Are you sure you want a jar file? not a War to deploy it to an app server?

Comment: I build the jar and run in docker.  src/main/resouces includes the following files:application.properties.qqwry.dat.  and ,private static final String APP_CONFIG = "application.properties";in = PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(APP_CONFIG) ; apProperties.load(in); is Ok.

Comment: sorry .new here .don't know how to edit the comment in a elegant  way